# How to run this complex mysql query as raw query in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a mysql query and is working totally fine when I run this query in phpmyadmin. The raw sql query is

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(u.id) > 1
     , GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a.amenity_name, '_' ,a.id)), a.amenity_name) as m_concat
     , u.id as unit_id
     , u.building_id
     , (uav.id) as uav_id
     , a.* 
  FROM amenities a 
  JOIN amenity_values av 
    ON a.id = av.amenity_id 
  JOIN units_amenities_values uav 
    ON av.id = uav.amenity_value_id 
  JOIN units u ON u.id = uav.unit_id 
 where a.category_id = 370 
   AND a.property_id = 82 
   AND u.building_id = 1265 
 group 
    by u.id 
 order 
    by u.id asc
```

But, when I try to run the exact query as raw query in laravel it is throwing error. I am trying to run it as:

```
$statement = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT IF(COUNT(u.id) > 1, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a.amenity_name, '_' ,a.id)), a.amenity_name) as m_concat, u.id as unit_id, u.building_id, (uav.id) as uav_id, a.* FROM amenities a INNER JOIN amenity_values av ON a.id = av.amenity_id INNER JOIN units_amenities_values uav ON av.id = uav.amenity_value_id INNER JOIN units u ON u.id = uav.unit_id where a.category_id = '370' AND a.property_id = '82' AND u.building_id = '1265' group by u.id order by u.id asc"));
```

While running the exact above statement, it throws following errors:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'amenity_db_prod.a.amenity_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: SELECT IF(COUNT(u.id) > 1, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a.amenity_name, '_' ,a.id)), a.amenity_name) as m_concat, u.id as unit_id, u.building_id, (uav.id) as uav_id, a.* FROM amenities a INNER JOIN amenity_values av ON a.id = av.amenity_id INNER JOIN units_amenities_values uav ON av.id = uav.amenity_value_id INNER JOIN units u ON u.id = uav.unit_id where a.category_id = '370' AND a.property_id = '82' AND u.building_id = '1265' group by u.id order by u.id asc)
```

Comment: Change `strict` option to false in mysql array of your `config/database.php`.

Comment: this query should produce the same error in mysql ..(there is an improper use of group by)  ... seems not a laravel issue to me..   anyway you should add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: `working totally fine` hm

Comment: @scaisEdge maybe `phpmyadmin` connects differently to the database than Laravel?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova  a raw query is a raw query and is executed by the same db engine ..for both the 'client'  .. ( phpmyadmin or laravle app) .. eventually the OP use two different db one for develop with version < 5.7 that allow a diferent sql_mode  for group by

Comment: @IvankaTodorova It looks like changing strict to false works fine. However, I want to know, is there any way to make it work without changing strick to false? Is it because that I have used value for category.id, property.id, building.id? Actually this value comes in $request. I was just testing it directly using value, just for test.